# Inner join syntax error but now sure what the error is

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

I am trying to count the number of records where the person's first name starts with B and the record created date is before 01-01-2021. It's saying I'm getting a syntax error but not sure why!

I have to do two inner joins because table a has the created date information which has a customer_ID that matches with table b which has the customer's name_id's, and the name_id's are in table c which has the first name information.

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_id 
INNER JOIN table_c c b.customer_id ON = c.name_id
WHERE c.first_name like 'B%'
AND a.created_date::text like '2021-01-01%'
group by count
```

Can someone please help me explain what's wrong with my syntax? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your second INNER JOIN has an issue: `INNER JOIN tablc_c c b_customer_id` is wrong. Read your first INNER JOIN and see if you can figure out what's different.

Comment: `LIKE` is not used for date values, only strings, and `LIKE` is not going to give you dates that are less than 01-01-2021. You also don't need `::text` after the date column, as you want it to still be a date.